# Rdkit: MaeMolSupplier NameError

Tags: python-3.x, bioinformatics, rdkit

I would like to able to extract details about a molecule in ".mae" format. I imported the rdkit.Chem.rdmolfiles functions and it seems to work for MolFromSmiles, but not for MaeMolSupplier as suggested in the 2019 documentation. Instead I get a NameError. Any aid/help in calling this function would be greatly appreciated.

**Works OK with MolFromSmiles**

```
import rdkit
from rdkit.Chem.rdmolfiles import *

mol = MolFromSmiles('C1NCN1')
print(mol)

(my-rdkit-env) [Me]$ python3 testrdkit.py 
<rdkit.Chem.rdchem.Mol object at 0x7f237f917030>
```

**Now to show the error**

```
import rdkit
from rdkit.Chem.rdmolfiles import *
suppl = MaeMolSupplier(file('five.mae'))
print(suppl)

my-rdkit-env) [Me]$ python3 testrdkit.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testrdkit.py", line 8, in <module>
    suppl = MaeMolSupplier(file('five.mae'))
NameError: name 'MaeMolSupplier' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you show the output of: `python -c 'import rdkit; print(rdkit.__version__)'` It may be the rdkit version you are using as it works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

import * doesn't work here either.

Just import rdmolfiles.

```
from rdkit.Chem import rdmolfiles
suppl = rdmolfiles.MaeMolSupplier('five.mae')
print(suppl)
<rdkit.Chem.rdmolfiles.MaeMolSupplier object at 0x000002792CEFC5B0>
```

Comment: Using your import style, this also did not work. Maybe the library is not completed somehow during the install? `AttributeError: module 'rdkit.Chem.rdmolfiles' has no attribute 'MaeMolSupplier'`